# Drag map by clicking on symbol

Tags: google-maps-api-3

There's a feature of google maps called SYMBOLS that allows you to draw different symbols on GoogleMaps. One example on google website that is located here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom

This draws a yellow star on a map, but I can't click the star and drag a map. I would like to be able to click the yellow star (so that a closed hand icon appears) and drag the map. I can do this while not hovering over the yellow star...how can I do this while hovering over the yellow star?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `clickable:false` on the marker if you don't want it to accept mouse events.